# java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException trying to filter with a jTextField

Tags: java, swing

i made a method that help me to filter rows of a `jTable` with what i write in a `jTextField` the problem is that when i try to write in the `jTextField` more than 8 letters it throws an error called...

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 9
at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1907) at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1907)
at vocaciones.test_consulta.filtrar(test_consulta.java:338)
at vocaciones.test_consulta.jTextField1KeyTyped(test_consulta.java:350)
at vocaciones.test_consulta.access$000(test_consulta.java:21)
at vocaciones.test_consulta$1.keyTyped(test_consulta.java:79)
at java.awt.Component.processKeyEvent(Component.java:6460)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(JComponent.java:2828)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6282)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1895)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:762)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1027)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:899)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:727)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4731)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

This is the mothod...

```
private void jTextField1KeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                     
    String text = jTextField1.getText().toUpperCase();
    jTextField1.setText(text);

    String selArt, desBd;
    String desBD = jTextField1.getText();

    int cdes = desBD.length();
    int row = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < jTable1.getRowCount(); i++) {
        selArt = (String) jTable1.getValueAt(i, 1);
        desBd = selArt.substring(0, cdes);

        if(desBd.equalsIgnoreCase(desBD.toUpperCase())){
            row = i;
            i = jTable1.getRowCount()+1;
        }
    } 

    jTable1.changeSelection(row, 2, false, false );
    jTable1.setSelectionBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
}
```

I hope you can help me solve this and thanks in advance!.

Comment: Check the length of selArt and see if it is within range of cdes

Comment: seems like the lenght of `selArt` depends of the first letter i write because then it filters the jTable rows and just shows the rows who starts with that letter and the lenght is defined by the information that is on that first row...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets Check your `Exception`

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" 
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 9<-----(1)
at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1907) at  <------(2)
```

1. `StringIndexOutOfBoundException` Name of The `Exception` you are getting
2. `java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1907)` Cause of `Exception`

> the problem is that when i try to write in the jTextField more than 8
>   letters it throws an error called...

In your code at `desBd = selArt.substring(0, cdes);` for `cdec >8 say 9` Exception is generated because `selArt`'s length is 8.

- `int cdes = desBD.length();` So `cdec` you are getting from `JTextField`'s `String`
- `selArt = (String) jTable1.getValueAt(i, 1);` and selArt you are getting from `JTable`

So to Use `cdes` which is length of `String` of `JTextField` which may be `>lengthOfString'selArt'`

Comment: in fact, it seems like the first thing that `stArt` gets as its length defines the max lenght of it.

I tried using different data on the `jTable` and the length changed.

Answer (score 0):

You got this exception, because `cdes > selArt.length()`. Check the `cdes` value before to use it on `substring` method.

```
if(cdes <= selArt.length()){
  desBd = selArt.substring(0, cdes);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple issue just check whether the `jTable1.getValueAt(i, 1);` `i=9` is present or not by printing `jTable1.getRowCount()`

```
for (int i = 0; i <= jTable1.getRowCount(); i++) {
i<=jTable1.getRowCount()
```